# How to make a C program pointer point to itself

Tags: c

I have a C program and I have to modify it so that `a` links to itself, `b` links to `c` and `c` links to `b`.

It does compile.  But I'm not sure if I did it correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *n;
  } a,b,c;

  a.data=1;
  b.data=2;
  c.data=3;
  b.n=c.n=NULL;
  a.n=a.n=NULL;
  a.n= &c;
  c.n= &b;

  printf(" %p\n", &(c.data)); 
  printf("%p\n",&(c.n));
  printf("%d\n",(*(c.n)).data);
  printf("%d\n", b.data);
  printf("integer %d is stored at memory address %p \n",a.data,&(a.data) );
  printf("the structure a is stored at memory address %p \n",&a );
  printf("pointer %p is stored at memory address %p \n",a.n,&(a.n) );
  printf("integer %i is stored at memory address %p \n",c.data,&(c.data) );
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

How do I have a pointer link to itself?

Comment: It seems that a.n has been set to c's address, b.n has been set to NULL and c.n has been set to b's address.  That does not match your description of what you were supposed to do.

Comment: Consider using typedef on structs for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
list *a, *b, *c;
a=(list *)malloc(sizeof (list));
b=(list *)malloc(sizeof (list));
c=(list *)malloc(sizeof (list));
```

- a links to itself

  ```
  a->n=a;
  ```
- b links to c

  ```
  b->n=c;
  ```
- c links to b

  ```
  c->n=b;
  ```

Can you see what you did wrong?

Comment: Better now ... but casting the return vale from malloc is frowned upon in `C`.

Comment: Why use memory allocation at all? She didn't ask about that, and it just complicates things unnecessarily.

Comment: @prm, so is pretending `sizeof` is a function, but that's not stopping you :)

Comment: @Blindy: If I were pretending it to be a function I'd write `sizeof(list)`. Note no space ...

Comment: @prm, you can have spaces in function calls too. What's the point of the parenthesis then?

Comment: See the C Standard 6.5.3 (page 90) (WG14 N1256 @ http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards) and 6.5.3.4 (page 92). I look at it as doing a cast of ... of nothing: `sizeof ((char)42)` == `sizeof (char)`;

Comment: @pmg, not following you. An operator is an operator, it doesn't need paranthesis. You don't write `-(2)`, you write `-2`.

Comment: The parenthesis in `sizeof(double)` do not "belong to" the operator. They belong to the operand. It is a syntax error to write `sizeof double`: the operand to the sizeof operator is a type enclosed in parenthesis or a unary expression (with optional, but bad form, parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

You say:

```
a links to itself, b links to c and c links to b
```

Then in your code you write this:

```
b.n=c.n=NULL;
a.n=a.n=NULL;
```

Let's go step by step:

```
b.n=c.n=NULL;
```

Break it down in:

```
c.n=NULL;
b.n=c.n;
```

Instead of assigning c to b and b to c you're assigning NULL to c.n and then the value of c.n (NULL, since you just did so) to b.c.

My C is a little weak but you probably wants something like this:

```
b.n = &c;
c.n = &b;
```

This uses & the address-of operator. The same works for the `a.n=a.n=NULL;` expression.

Comment: So if i just get rid of b.n=c.n=NULL; ??

Answer (score 1):

```
b.n=c.n=NULL;
a.n=a.n=NULL;
```

b and c link to nowhere; a links to nowhere (twice)

```
a.n= &c;
c.n= &b;
```

a links to c; c links to b

You wanted a linking to a; b linking to c, and c linking to b ... so ... FAIL :-)

Comment: Hmmm... I think I need to change a few things! Thanks